# jquery mobile - remove icon disc in the header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jqm 1.4.5 to create an application but I have a problem about icons.
I got remove all the disc from the icons with a **class=ui-nodisc-icon** but when I get to the header icons the disc does not come out. Someone was able to remove the disc from the icons in the header?

print https://i.postimg.cc/v81SLPZx/2019-02-26-00-10-54.png

Comment: Dear Rui, you should also post your page header code example. Make your job easier by making our job easier.

Comment: @Gajotres ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
  <div data-role="header">
    <div id="custom-border-radius">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">No text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And some CSS:

```
#custom-border-radius .ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-corner-all {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kv1jayLe/

If this is it please do not forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ui-nodisc-icon` class is used for the icon `background`, not for the button itself.

Here is the reference [Icons - jQuery Mobile Demos](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/) :

> The semi-transparent dark circle behind the icon ensures good contrast
>   on any background color so it works well with the jQuery Mobile
>   theming system.

If You need a *full-flat* design, You can wrap the buttons inside a container with the `.ui-noboxshadow` class **(see my explanation below)** and declare the border and the background of the button as transparent. If You need to do that for all Your `.ui-nodisc-icon` buttons, remoove the  `.ui-header` selector from the `css`.

```css
.ui-header .ui-alt-icon.ui-nodisc-icon.ui-btn.ui-btn-icon-notext {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <div class="ui-noboxshadow">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-alt-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      Shadow, disc: <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-alt-icon ui-icon-bars" >Menu</a>
      <br>
      Shadow, no-disc: <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-alt-icon ui-icon-bars" >Menu</a>
      <br>
      No-shadow, no-disc: <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-alt-icon ui-icon-bars" >Menu</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**To clarify my answer**, please note: You don't need to add an extra `div` to Your markup, it is just enough that Your buttons are inside a container with the class `.ui-noboxshadow`. For instance, You can add the class to the `header`. So, this will achieve the same result:

```
<div data-role="header" class="ui-noboxshadow">
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-alt-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon">Menu</a>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```